# Take the points where the second column is the smallest

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

```
bins = array([[2076., -861.84471079],
       [2076., -858.23866597],
       [2076., -861.84471079],
       ...,
       [9757., 1847.33889178],
       [9757., 1830.39082856],
       [9757., -932.14347751]])
```

I want to take the point with the smallest y for each unique number in first column

```
bins = array([[2076., -858.2386],
       [9757., -932.14]])
```

What would be a simple solution for numpy?

Comment: The bins you provided is just a list of points, ie: one bin

Comment: in which sense -838.2386 is the smallest? And -932.14?

Comment: -858.2386 is the smallest for 2076
-932.1434 is the smallest for 9757

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `pandas` to group points by x value, then calculate the min in each group as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
bins = np.array([[2076., -861.84471079],
       [2076., -858.23866597],
       [2076., -861.84471079],
       [9757., 1847.33889178],
       [9757., 1830.39082856],
       [9757., -932.14347751]])
print(bins.shape)
df = pd.DataFrame(bins, columns=['x', 'y'])
np.array(df.loc[df.groupby(['x'])['y'].idxmin()])
```